# In the linux kernel, where is the first process initialized?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm looking for the code in the linux kernel (2.4.x) that initializes the first process, pid=0.

Many searches provided many clues, but I still cannot find it.

Any pointers, anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The initial task struct is set up by the macro `INIT_TASK()`, defined in `include/linux/init_task.h`.  All other task structs are created by `do_fork`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I would add that `init/init_task.c` also sets up the `thread_info` and kernel stack for PID 0 (on the boot CPU only) using `INIT_THREAD_INFO()`. Then, for the x86 architecture, `startup_32` (in `arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S`) loads a pointer to the PID 0 kernel stack into ESP. From that point on, Linux is in "process context" for PID 0.

Answer (score 1):

[start_kernel()](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Linux-i386-Boot-Code-HOWTO/init_main.html)

check out rest_init() at the end

```
// idle process, pid = 0
cpu_idle();     // never return
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already looking at that page, so now I know I was on the right path.

Where in there is the first task_struct created and populated?

Comment: Which process has pid=0? Are you talking about something before `init`?

Comment: The problem I was asked to solve was to add a field to task_struct. I'd like to initialize it, and have each fork() copy it, but can't find where the initial value is set.

Comment: At least with the 2.6 kernel, I think `init` always gets pid 0.

Comment: `init` always gets a PID of 1.  PID zero is the 'idle' process.

Answer (score 1):

The first process that the kernel initializes is the swapper process or the idle thread. This thread runs forever. When no other process is active in the system, then this thread [which is cpu_idle() function found in arch/arm/kernel/process.c for the ARM architecture] calls the architecture dependent pm_idle function, which power collapses the CPU until a timer interrupt or some other interrupt wakes it up.

The swapper process [pid=0] is initialized in arch/arm/kernel/init_task.c by the macro INIT_TASK.